# Get a result based on previous row in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, analysis, rank

I am struggling with the following. I am analysing of what happened after first attempt. `Rank` > 1

I managed to prepare the data, by ranking (`Rank`)  based on `Date`. In the example below, I`m trying to get all Rows with `ID1` from `Col1`, as `ID1` has the same value (`TEST1`) in `Col2`.

I am not interested in `ID2` or `ID3` as they don't have another `Test1` anymore.

```
df(print)

Col1    Col2    Date    Rank
ID1     TEST1   01/07   1
ID2     TEST1   01/07   1
ID3     TEST1   01/07   1
ID1     TEST1   02/07   2
ID2     TEST2   02/07   2
ID3     TEST3   04/07   2
```

Desired output

```
df(print)

Col1    Col2    Date    Rank
ID1     TEST1   01/07   1
ID1     TEST1   02/07   2
```

I have tried the `if else` and `np.where` statement, but those did not work.

Edit: I want my query to automatically detect that TEST1 has rank 1 and provide me with data, if rank 2 has also TEST1.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas — it would be great if you specified that in the question, even in the title! And also tag "pandas".

Comment: Your question title really doesn't tell me much, I'm afraid. I totally understand that for a lot of people who are new to programming and maybe from a data analysis background, simply pandas===python.

Comment: I agree. My question is not reflecting of what I actually wanted to achieve. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how general you need this, but to get that output you can use

```py
df[(df['Col1']=='ID1') & (df['Rank']>1)]
```

In general `df[conditions]` where the conditions are joined by `&`, and are grouped by `(...)`, is similar to a SQL `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks. But I want my query to automatically detect that ```TEST1``` has rank 1 and provide me with data, if rank 2 has also ```TEST1```.